# One to One Relationship between primary key and unique key in EF6

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I'm trying to create a One-to-One relationship between two tables using a primary key and a unique key of the two tables (rather the primary keys).

The following is what I'd like to work.

```
// The principal end
public class A
{
    // The primary Key
    public int AId { get; set; }

    // The navigation property
    public virtual B B { get; set; }
}

// The dependent end
public class B
{
    // The primary Key
    public int BId { get; set; }

    // The unique key
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    public int AId { get; set; }

    // The navigation property
    public virtual A A { get; set; }
}
```

But then I see this error:

> Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'A' and 'B'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.

I'm quite sure a primarykey-uniquekey relationship is allowed in SQL Server. Looks like EF6 doesn't support it. EF Core 1.0 seems to, but it's not feasible to port to EF Core right now.

**Why we need a need a relationship of this kind:**
We have two tables `A` and `B` in production, but the one-to-one relationship, which should have been there is missing. The relationship is something we need so we can *navigate* from an `A` object to a `B` object with EF. Since both tables have values, we can't really make the primary key, the foreign key - we'll end up with incorrect data.

My approach to fixing this was to:

1. add a column
2. fill it with the correct `A` ids
3. make it unique
4. establish the 1-1 relationship

An alternate approach to fixing this is more than welcome.

Comment: Take a look at [Associations in EF Code First: Part 5 – One-to-One Foreign Key Associations](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-5-one-to-one-foreign-key-associations). According to that, you can somehow setup such relationship, but only as unidirectional, i.e. without `A.B` navigation property.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with EF Core using Fluent API's .HasPrincipalKey() method. Unfortunately not supported in EF6 which is a shame as relationships over unique keys can essentially be treated the same as foreign key constrains so I'd imagine it would have been an easy addition.

Now that MS has forgot about EF6 and is focusing on EF Core, this will never happen. I really liked using the visual entity designers as it saved so much time. Looking at the thousand+ lines of code the EF Core DbContext scaffold generator spits out for me is discouraging to say the least. Sure, it's pretty when you're dealing with a demo project consisting of two cute tables but we all know this is never the case in the real world. The whole point of using an ORM is to save time but I'm not sure if having to manage thousands of lines of configuration code is any better. Just by two cents.